# Facebook SDK for Unity with mobile apps

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm planning on building Unity mobile apps using the Facebook SDK for Unity.

However it seems before the app can be authorized it needs to be in the store. As it seems from my app page:
[image: Facebook for Mobile Apps]

Also how can I get the connection allowed via UnityEditor for debugging as well:
[image: What to use for Unity Editor?]

None of these seem to make sense to me :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the store id's to make it work, then it would never work. You can also switch your app to sandbox mode, but be aware that only users in this facebook project will have a opportunity to login and act properly.

If you want to debug in the UnityEditor, you should get the newest (BETA) facebook SDK version, and the platforms set should be the platform that you are aiming (for mobile: android, ios). UnityEditor will take care of itself, giving you link to get app token to login in the editor.

Don't forget to follow all normal steps of setting your app properly in unity, just like in the documentation of Facebook Unity SDK.